# Paper.js external file will not load

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am just trying to get into paper.js. Code works fine when they're inlined. But when I move them to an external file and src it there, errors starts to pop up :( Can anyone figure out what I did wrong? Error screenshot is attached

Much thanks!

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c39ac.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Paper.js Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/paper/dist/paper-full.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/paperscript" src="test.js" canvas="myCanvas"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your screenshot, it is CORS ERROR.

You can fix CORS ERROR to test locally with
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out, turns out there's a same origin policy to chrome so I was cockblocked :P

Comment: Though I'm still putting your answer as THE answer because I really appreciate the fact that you took the time to look into my specific issue and came up with a solution :) I've also upvoted your comment, but my rep is too low so the vote is counted but not shown :(

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to run this through a server to link the two files, either setting up an XAMPP server yourself or publishing your files to a hosted server so the http://... protocol can be used rather than file:/// (your case, because you are using a localhost).

One way to do this and solve your problem is:

1) navigate to your project folder in the terminal

2) if you have python v2.x installed then run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

or for python v3.x:

```
python -m http.server
```

3) open up your browser and navigate to http://localhost:8000

4) select and open your .html file

It worked for me.

More details in related topic: ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out chrome has a same origin policy so I was cockblocked. Sapics' solution works, but if you want to take the easier route, if you're on mac (like I am), just go to terminal and type in "open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir", this'll open chrome without the cockblock

Edit: I'm putting Sapics' answer as the correct answer because I really appreciate the fact that he took the time to look into my specific issue and came up with a solution :)