# Paperjs loading external Javascript file for Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vx3I.png)

Loaded  external script linking to My canvas but I'm getting this Error.

But when i use

> python SimpleHttpServer

Module it works fine.

```
<script type="text/paperscript" src="js/welcome_canvas.js" canvas="welcome-canvas"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is CORS(Cross-origin resource sharing) ERROR, not a bug.
Your method `python SimpleHttpServer` is one of the method which bypass CORS ERROR.
[Paper.js external file will not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495026/paper-js-external-file-will-not-load) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in ordinary you can't use ajax-requests for local files because of security politics.

But you can setup flag for Google Chrome which allow you do this [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)